# Angularjs : call to REST API to get a docx document from server

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I am trying to call a service from angularjs that produces a docx document.

Angularjs is supposed to display the save prompt of the web browser, and then save the document.

When I open the saved document, what I get in the docx file is :

> Undefined

Api rest :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create-avenant",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public void getAvenant(@RequestBody AvenantDTO avenant, HttpServletResponse response) {
    contratService.createAvenant(response, avenant);
}
```

service produces a XWPFDocument and send to browser :

```
private void sendDocToBrowser(HttpServletResponse response, XWPFDocument doc) throws IOException {
    try
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        doc.write(baos);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=myDoc.docx");
        response.setContentType("application/docx");
        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        baos.writeTo(outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
    }
    finally
    {
       outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Angularjs :

```
Avenant.create(avenant,function(result){
    var blob = new Blob([result.body], { type: 'application/docx' });
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    link.download = 'file.docx';
    link.click();
})
```

Comment: Can you please try changing `produces` to `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE` in controller

Comment: some mistake in my code, I have new Blob([result.body], { type: 'application/docx' }); that gives me undefined. If I do : new Blob([result.body], { type: 'application/docx' });, I am getting [object object] in the docx document.

Comment: same issue with APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE